# Connecting React Component with Redux Store

Tags: redux, react-redux

Very basic simple GET example for react-redux

I have a "MockAPI" which simulates a GET request to an API like so:

```
const dashboards = [
  {
    "Id":1,
    "title":"Overview"
  },
  {
    "Id":2,
    "title":"Overview"
  },
  {
    "Id":3,
    "title":"Overview"
  },
  {
    "Id":4,
    "title":"Overview"
  }
];

class DashboardApi {
  static getAllDashboards() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(Object.assign([], dashboards));
      }, delay);
    });
  }
}
```

I am trying to develop in a react-redux flow of dispatching an action via a button click and then updating the component via the redux store.

Here is my component code:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as dashboardActions from '../../actions/dashboardActions';

class HomePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.loadDashboards = this.loadDashboards.bind(this);
  }

  loadDashboards() {
    this.props.dispatch(dashboardActions.loadDashboards());
  }

  dashboardItem(dashboard, index) {
    return <p key={index}>{dashboard.title}</p>;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <h1>
            Hello World!
            <button onClick={this.loadDashboards}>load</button>
          </h1>
          {this.props.dashboards.map(this.dashboardItem)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

HomePage.propTypes = {
  dashboards: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    dashboards: state.dashboards
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomePage);
```

And here is my `dashboardActions.js`:

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import dashboardApi from '../mockApi/mockDashboardApi';

export function loadDashboardsSuccess(dashboards) {
    return { type: types.LOAD_DASHBOARDS_SUCCESS, dashboards };
}

export function loadDashboards() {
    return dispatch => {
        return dashboardApi
            .getAllDashboards()
            .then(dashboards => {
                dispatch(loadDashboardsSuccess(dashboards));
            });
    };
}
```

And here is my reducer:

```
import initialState from './initialState';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

export default function dashboardReducer(state = initialState.dashboards, action) {
    switch(action.types) {
        case types.LOAD_DASHBOARDS_SUCCESS:
            return action.dashboards;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the onClick to load in the dashboards array and to render as `<p>` tags simply displaying the `title` value. Unfortunately it is not happening.

I see that the LOAD_DASHBOARDS_SUCCESS action is getting loaded, but I see that the `dashboards` property in the store is still an empty array instead of showing the returned data...

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you've got a typo in your reducer. `switch(action.types)` should be `switch(action.type)` with no 's'.

Comment: You are a genius.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a typo in your reducer. `switch(action.types)` should be `switch(action.type)` with no 's'

Comment: Well now. This was embarrassing.

Comment: Happens to all of us. Sometimes an extra set of eyes helps.